# Refresh a UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, uiwebview, refresh

I'm looking for a simple way of adding a refresh mechanism to my UIWebView. I've seen posts about the EGO pull to refresh but, to be honest, I don't understand how that works, especially since I have no clue on how to use it with a UIWebView instead of a table view. And it seems to me like a lot of overhead for just a simple refresh.

I thought about adding a navbar but instead of a back button, add a custom "refresh" one. But based on what I've found so far, it seems as complicated as the other solution.

So, basically, I'd like to know what you would do. Keep in mind that the only requirement is that the user have some easy way of refreshing the view. Any suggestion ?

*I'm a begginer in Objective-C so that is why I don't understand how to plug the EGO framework with a UIWebView even after downloading and running the code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well,

Create a button and inside button's IBAction,

```
- (IBAction) performReload:(id) sender {
    [self.uiwebview reload];
}
```

Check the documentation, it will help you a lot at your beginning stage.

### Visual Suggestion:

[image]
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thanks. I've red that, but the question is : where do I put the button to make look not too ugly... I think you'll say upper corner. I'll try to give a custom look like a long slim one.

Comment: Ohh I thought it's a technical coding question and not UI design related. But yeah I would just put it upper right corner with default refresh icon in it! So user knows that this button means refresh. Try to have icon similar to Safari web browser so in that way you will be maintaining the aesthetic appeal of iOS :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. And the question was both design + technical. If anyone can point me a simple way to use the pull to refresh pattern, I'll give it a try, since it's the best as far as design is concern.

Comment: Well that is a great visual thanks ! I'll try it right now ! Thaks a lot for your help. I accept your answer as it is.