# Simple iOS app to show my site in UIWebView *with* back / refresh controllers

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

Looking all over for a simple Xcode project that will load my web site in a UIWebView that has the default Safari controllers for back / refresh the page - but can't seem to find one.

All I could find was a great template project, but it didn't have the controllers. And since I am very new to iOS development, I can't figure out how to add the controllers.

Can anyone help me out with complete source for something like that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

- Add a navigationbar above or a toolbar under the webview
- Put two barbuttonitems/buttons into the bar, one for back and one for forward. Of course you can also use the segmented control
- Set the webview's delegate to the view controller of the view
- In the TouchDown-actions of the buttons, call webView's `goBack:` or `goForward:` methods

For the method references, see here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/goBack

The same can of course be done with reload (the method is called `refresh`), and this SO even shows an example of how  to do it:
[Refresh a UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043106/refresh-a-uiwebview)